# ModuleNotFoundError when running python script from a batch file

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, google-translate

I have a simple python script called `sc.py` that translates a word. This is my code:

```
#! python3

from googletrans import Translator
import sys

translator = Translator()

dest = 'hr'

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    try:
        dest = sys.argv[2]
    except:
        pass

    translated = translator.translate(sys.argv[1],  dest = dest)
    print(translated.text)
```

The script works as expected when I run it from command line, for example like this:

```
python sc.py something it
```

And I get the expected result:

```
qualcosa
```

Then I created a batch file so I can call this script from anywhere by just writing `translate`. This is my batch file called `translate.bat` :

```
@py.exe D:\path\to\the\script\sc.py %*
```

I've added the folder where the batch file to the path, but when I try to run it I get `ModuleNotFoundError` like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\path\to\the\script\sc.py", line 3, in <module>
    from googletrans import Translator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googletrans'
```

I have no idea why this is happening, has anyone encountered anything similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That could be there is multiple version of python installed or install `googletrans` for all version of python.

Use

```
python D:\path\to\the\script\sc.py %*
```

instead of

```
@py.exe D:\path\to\the\script\sc.py %*
```

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.7, type following in CMD:

```
CD C:\Users\[path]\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
```

then:

```
pip3 install googletrans
```