# Getting ModuleNoteFoundError running python (3.7) from batch file

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file

I am trying to run a python script from a batch file, but it is returning a moduleNotFound error for pandas. I have python 3.7 and use anaconda/spyder, pandas is installed and the script works fine in spyder. I found a very similar question, but the solution offered failed to work for me.

([ModuleNotFoundError when running python script from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275817/modulenotfounderror-when-running-python-script-from-a-batch-file))

```
@echo off
"...\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6\python.exe" "...\Code\main.py" %*
pause
```

Both with and without the %* has failed to work. Not used to using .bat, help and guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: add `conda activate` in  script

Comment: Apologies, if you could clarify a bit, do you mean add "conda activate" after @echo off?

Comment: yes, since your code in python file is based on the anaconda python envronmnet not on the system python env i sugeest you to replicate step in bash to create anaconda env and invoke anaconda env before executing python file